# Can't instantiate class no empty constructor when calling Class.newInstance()

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a `RadioGroup` in my custom Dialog class using the following bit of code:

```
public static Dialog singleChoiceRB(
    Activity a
    , String title
    , CharSequence[] items
    , Class<?> itemListener
    , OnClickListener pocl
    , String pocl_txt){

MyCustomDialog dialog = MyCustomDialog();
// Setup stuff in here //

RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(a);

for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(a);
    rb.setText(items[i]);
    RadioButtonOptionOnClick rbooc;
    try {
        rbooc = (RadioButtonOptionOnClick) itemListener.newInstance(); // <-- failing here
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        continue;
    }
    rbooc.setWhich(i);
    rb.setOnClickListener(rbooc);
    rg.addView(rb);
}

dialog.addBodyView(rg);
return dialog.getDialog();
}
```

I have an abstract class called `RadioButtonOptionClick`

```
public abstract class RadioButtonOptionOnClick implements OnClickListener{
  protected int which;

  public RadioButtonOptionOnClick(){
  }

  public void setWhich(int which){
    this.which = which;
  }
}
```

And the class that extends it

```
public class ScanButtonFragmentConfirmOnClick extends RadioButtonOptionOnClick{
  public ScanButtonFragmentConfirmOnClick(){
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    setConfirmGuid(which);
  }
}
```

I'm calling my dialog constructor here

```
confirm = MyDialogFunctions.singleChoiceRB(
    a
    , c.getString(R.string.checkInConfirm)
    , s.toArray(new CharSequence[s.size()])
    , ScanButtonFragmentConfirmOnClick.class
    , new OnConfirmClick(c, a)
    , getString(android.R.string.ok)
    );
confirm.show();
```

The error I'm catching is this

> java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class
>   {MyPackage}.ScanButtonFragment$OnItemClick; no empty constructor

As you can see, I have empty constructors in both `ScanButtonFragmentConfirmOnClick` and `RadioButtonOptionOnClick`. What is going on that is throwing that error? `OnClickListener` has no constructor since it is an interface, is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head against this for a good while, I tried moving ScanButtonFragmentConfirmOnClick out from my Fragment where it was nested into its own class and lo and behold that worked.

Also, for kicks and giggles, I tried to make the nested class static and that did the trick as well.

Moral of the story is, don't use non-static nested classes when attempting to call `Class.newInstance()`. It doesn't work.